# How can I get the potion in "Having", level 69 of Spelling Jungle?

Tags: spelling-jungle

I'm trying to get the red "L" potion on the far right of the screen, and failing.  How can I get it?

[image: screenshot]

For those who haven't played this game, the mud makes you slide — whatever direction you start moving in, you continue in until you hit a rock/water/grass/etc.  To get the potion I would need to feed the apple to the hippo and ride it over there, but I can't get the apple.  Sliding towards the apple from the space immediately to the right of it makes me fall into the pit.  Sliding towards it from further to the right doesn't work since the wind spirit blows you downwards, and I think I'd just slide into the pit again otherwise anyways.

Comment: There's nothing that stops you from sliding? Like an item or somthing usable?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately not.

Comment: A second spelling jungle question by you. I *really* need to play this again. Perhaps we can turn gaming.stackexchange into the go-to resource for spelling jungle.

Comment: @Wipqozn I'll do my best :P [one more](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29215/how-can-i-get-the-potion-in-many-level-72-of-spelling-jungle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the potion. However, it is totally unnecessary. It (and the apple) is just a distraction to delay you from beating the level.

Comment: Sadly I think this is probably correct.