# How can I get the potion in "Thirsty", level 46 of Spelling Jungle?

Tags: spelling-jungle

Like in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28989/how-can-i-get-the-potion-in-having-level-69-of-spelling-jungle), I'm trying to get a difficult-to-reach potion here (the blue one towards the right side of the level).  However, I'm not sure it's actually possible to get this one.

[image: screenshot]

It looks like I might be able to throw a bridge from above it (beside the <kbd>T</kbd>) but I need the bridge to get back across the water after getting the letters on the left side.  I can't see any way to use the rock to get back across, since it falls into the pit when you cross over the first time.  Oh, and I checked — there are no invisible platforms over the pits.

Is it possible to get this potion?  If so, how?

Comment: AWESOME GAME IS AWESOME. I used to own this. I need to download this and play it again.

Comment: @Wipqozn Indeed.  I just finished beating the game, apart from getting these danged potions for the sake of it. I also discovered the sequel, Spelling Blizzard, which should be more good fun.

Comment: Haven't really played this game (yet), but I assume you push the right boulder into the water to get across in the first place.  Does the boulder disappear once you walk across it to push the other boulder into the pit?

Comment: @APrough Yes, it sinks.

Comment: Still trying to get this thing installed (damn backwards-non-compatability).  One more question while I work on that.  I know you can push animals.  What happens when you push one into the water?  Do they float or drown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly comprehensive guide [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/934972-spelling-jungle/faqs/44591) which explains how to get most of the potions **BUT** makes no mention of how to get the one in question.

Based on that and the fact that it looks to be impossible I'm going to say that you cant.

It may be worth suggesting that it could be a joke on behalf of the game makers that the level "Thirsty" contains a drink you cannot get.

Comment: I also emailed the author of that guide to see if he could add anything.

Comment: I like that explanation a lot.